# Trading C++ Libraries

Tags: backtesting, algorithmic-trading, programming

Are there any free c++ libraries that would have some of the functions that would be used in developing a trading strategy. For instance, calculating drawdown, Volatility Forecasting, MAE, MFE....etc.

I know I could code these but this would help me save some time and focus on the strategy and not the report generations.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some suggestions.

Search Amazon (or your favorite bookseller) for books concerning "C++ quantitative finance." I found several titles that look promising.

I went to [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=trading%20system) (searching on "Trading Systems") and saw several promising systems that might give you a leg up in 
drawdown, MAE, etc.

I use TradeStation 9.0 for comparing various trading strategies. It will provide MAE/MFE graphs, trade equity curves, and rank strategies based on maximum drawdown. But be sure to read *Trading Systems That Work: Building and Evaluating Effective Trading Systems* by Thomas Stridsman for an apt critique of TradeStation's generated reports.

Answer (score 6):

These are the libraries I most prominently use for C++:

1. [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org)
2. [Boost C++ Libraries](http://boost.org)
3. This is not *specifically* a library however it is extremely helpful, [the Anaconda Compiler Tools](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/compiler-tools.html).
4. The [Armadillo C++ library for linear algebra & scientific computing](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).
5. The [Intel Math Kernel Library for C++ (MKL)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl).
6. The [Ta_Lib Technical Analysis Library](http://ta-lib.org/) has an [API for C/C++](https://ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html).
7. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a "C++ template library for linear algebra: matrices, vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms" as per their website. Eigen allows you to to do all sorts of computations with matrices of *any size*. It doesn't need anything other than the standard library, and the library tiself is standard with 98 to technically any C++m compiler should work (I use [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) rather than GCC for the record, which you can install with `sudo apt-get install clang`).

As far as

> calculating drawdown, Volatility Forecasting, MAE, MFE....etc.

goes, QuantLib does all of that and more! It is an extremely powerful library that can do a *lot of things*.

Answer (score 5):

For actually creating your trading strategy, you could use the open-source TA-Lib (written in C/C++) available [here](http://ta-lib.org/). To test it, you could use [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and the [PerformanceAnalytics package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/).

Comment: Sorry, but this is a clear -1: TAlib is written in C and is, for better or worse, or *technical analysis* library.  Why do you equate that to *trading strategy*? TAlib has nothing on drawdowns, vol forecasting etc pp.

Comment: The OP wanted "some of the functions that would be used in developing a trading strategy." Although I cannot quote any evidence in support, I am pretty sure that the tools of technical analysis are/can be used in developing such strategies. As to whether TAlib is written in C or C++, well I stand corrected.

Comment: C or C++? It is not the same

Comment: TAlib source is written in C, C++ Cli and Java

Answer (score 2):

QuantLib is widely used

http://quantlib.org/docs.shtml

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question: QuantLib is not for trading strategies but for derivative pricing.

Comment: @vonjd to me, derivative pricing is one of the part in the process of developing a trading strategy.

Comment: The question gives examples of what is meant: "calculating drawdown, Volatility Forecasting, MAE, MFE" - QuantLib can't do any of these.